# How to commit a Git repo to an empty repo SVN server?

Tags: git-svn

I have setup an empty svn on a server and I have been working on locally making commits along the way. Now I wish to commit my repo to an svn server. For this I tried:

```
git-svn checkout http://remote.svn.server.com
git-svn dcommit
```

Git complains that:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/git-svn line 411.
Committing to  ...
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history
```

Since I started on my local computer first, and the repo online is empty, I can't find any info on how to make this work.

Comment: Are you trying to commit to the SVN server *and preserve the commit logs* or just push the data into SVN in one big "Initial Commit?"

Comment: Have you actually cloned the svn repo yet?

Comment: @Steve Losh. Preserving the logs was my intention, but at this point being able to just do an Initial Commit will also be great. My commits are less than 20 now, so I would be very happy if I can just get this to work.

@tcurdt. I have done so now as you suggested below. But still getting same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
git-svn clone http://remote.svn.server.com otherdir
```

Then in other dir pull the changes locally from your previous dir. Then you should have a git repo that is "connected" via git-svn and you should be able to use dcommit on it.

[This](http://wiki.apache.org/general/GitAtApache) might also be a useful read.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. It seems even after pulling locally the gir repo was not connected.

Comment: paste your .git/config file ... a git-log would also be useful ... this really isn't a question for SO ... you should go and ask on IRC

Answer (score 30):

I needed something like this recently and the process is relatively straightforward.

There's good tutorial by Brandon Dimcheff, ["Commit a linear git history to subversion"](http://brandon.dimcheff.com/2009/01/04/commit-a-linear-git-history-to-subversion/) (replaces [old broken link](http://its.arubything.com/2009/1/4/commit-a-linear-git-history-to-subversion)), which these steps are based on.

As of Git version 1.6.3 these are the steps:

```
$ svnadmin create svn_repository
$ svn mkdir -m "Initial setup" file:///full/path/to/svn_repository/trunk

$ mkdir gitrepo && cd gitrepo
$ git init
$ echo 'Hello from Git' > file.txt
$ git add file.txt
$ git commit -m "Hello from Git"

$ git svn init --trunk=trunk file:///full/path/to/svn_repository/
$ git svn fetch

$ git branch -a # Lists remotes/trunk

$ git rebase --onto remotes/trunk --root master
# => Applying: Hello from Git etc.

$ git svn dcommit
# => Committing to ... Committed r2 ... etc
```

You can do a `svn checkout` of svn_repository now and see your Git repo.

Comment: Add `--log-window-size` to  `git svn fetch`, otherwise it will take ages on big repositories. =D