# Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history

Tags: git, git-svn

Why do I get this error message?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*(Posted Chad's "question" as an answer, fixed formatting and typos.)*

There are a couple of causes for this error message.

The first, being the most common. You have two disjoint histories in your git repository: The history that you made in git, and the history from the remote svn repository.

To fix this, you need to make your git repository and svn repository share one common ancestor so git can figure what commits have changed what.

The following [Article](http://brandon.dimcheff.com/2009/01/04/commit-a-linear-git-history-to-subversion/), discusses how to fix the problem:

The second possible cause of the problem is if you have an early version of git (possible, windows msysGit package) and you have just created a new git repository that communicates with a remote svn repository.

For example:

```
git svn init svn://svn.xxx.xxx/xxx/trunk
git svn fetch -r BASE:10
```

or

```
git clone svn://svn.xxx.xxx/xxx/trunk // Adds all the files in the revision...
```

And you get the follow error messages, when using the following commands.

```
$ git svn info
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree

$ git svn rebase
Unable determine upstream SVN information working tree history

$ git svn dcommit
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history
```

If you get the above error messages, first step is to check your git version. If your running a older git version <= 1.6.3.3.* that was in my case with (msysGit), then the easiest way to fix the problem is to update to a newest version of git such as 1.6.4.*.

The following [Article](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg107331.html) discusses the problem in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article, that let me do a switch do a different svn repository and now I'm back in business!

Comment: For the first common case, the instructions on the Article is out of date.  The poster here has updated instructions for the git beginners http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457694/how-to-commit-a-git-repo-to-an-empty-repo-svn-server/981765#981765

Comment: the http://eikke.com/importing-a-git-tree-into-a-subversion-repository/ helped me a lot

Comment: I had this problem because the url to the subversion repository had changed. Make sure you can access the path configured in git using an svn client.

Answer (score 40):

i got this message because of cloning the svn repo with `--no-metadata` option. Maybe that's the case with Your problem too.

When cloning it without that option everything is fine.

The `--no-metadata` option is meant to clone an SVN repository when the new `git` clone is to be come the canonical source in the future. It lacks the capacity to commit back to the SVN upstream, because it has no way to track differences between the git clone and the SVN upstream.

Comment: This is what I did.

Answer (score 18):

In my case, the HEAD from the svn repo should have been matched to the HEAD from the git repo. [This](http://rip747.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/reviving-a-git-svn-clone/) should solve the problem:

```
git update-ref refs/remotes/git-svn refs/remotes/origin/master
```

If your use a different git branch for svn trunk, for example `svntrunk`, that branch should be referenced instead, that is:

```
git update-ref refs/remotes/git-svn refs/remotes/origin/svntrunk
```

Comment: This did not fix my problem.

Comment: This fixed my problem.

Comment: Error: fatal: refs/remotes/origin/master: not a valid SHA1

Comment: Worked for me! `refs/remotes/origin/master` was instead `refs/remotes/origin/svntrunk` since I keep svn trunk into another branch. I add this in the post since it's a community wiki.

Comment: This reminded me that I only did `git clone` but **forgot `git svn init`** after that! This sequence worked: `git clone` → `git svn init` → `git update-ref`.

Answer (score 9):

I got this message after I incorrectly added the `-s`/`--stdlayout` parameter to the `git svn clone` command for a Subversion repo that did **not** have the "standard Subversion layout" of `trunk`, `tags`, and `branches` relative paths.

(The Subversion repos I usually clone do have the standard relative paths, so when I cloned a Subversion repo that didn't have them using my usual `git svn clone` command, I got this cryptic message. The message is 100% correct, but almost 100% useless when trying to figure out what the problem is.)

Comment: I ran into this problem because i had added /trunk to the svn url while doing `git svn clone` with the `-s` option. So while not entirely the same as your situation, your comment helped me discover my mistake. thx!

Answer (score 9):

got same problem, here is solution based on http://eikke.com/importing-a-git-tree-into-a-subversion-repository/ article:

```
$ git svn init http://server.com/svn/project/trunk/prototypes/proto1/
$ git svn fetch
  W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: '/svn/!svn/bc/100/dcom/trunk/prototypes/ws' path not found
  W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
  This may take a while on large repositories
  r147367 = 37c9910f794cb9cff7ca0d5d2eb26e1f0dabbc4d (refs/remotes/git-svn)
$ svn log http://server.com/svn/project/trunk/prototypes/proto1/
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  r147367 | user | 2014-01-16 18:02:43 +0100 (Thu, 16 Jan 2014) | 1 line
  proto1 home
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ git log --pretty=oneline master | tail -n1
  71ceab2f4776089ddbc882b8636aacec1ba5e832 Creating template
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ #1

$ git show-ref git-svn
  37c9910f794cb9cff7ca0d5d2eb26e1f0dabbc4d refs/remotes/git-svn
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ #2

$ echo "71ceab2f4776089ddbc882b8636aacec1ba5e832 37c9910f794cb9cff7ca0d5d2eb26e1f0dabbc4d" >> .git/info/grafts

$ git svn dcommit
  Committing to http://server.com/svn/project/trunk/prototypes/proto1 ...
    A   README.md
    A   pom.xml
A   src/main/java/.gitkeep
A   src/main/resources/.gitkeep
A   src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
A   src/main/webapp/index.html
A   webapps/.gitkeep
  Committed r147419
    A   README.md
    A   pom.xml
A   src/main/java/.gitkeep
A   src/main/resources/.gitkeep
A   src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
A   src/main/webapp/index.html
A   webapps/.gitkeep
  r147419 = 6a8bda7262739306d0a6e17eaad2802737dedc35 (refs/remotes/git-svn)
  No changes between current HEAD and refs/remotes/git-svn
  Resetting to the latest refs/remotes/git-svn
  Unstaged changes after reset:
    M   pom.xml
    M   src/main/webapp/index.html
    A   .gitignore
  Committed r147420
    M   pom.xml
    M   src/main/webapp/index.html
    A   .gitignore
  r147420 = 749b5acec55c341672bca08d07de8c336b5a4701 (refs/remotes/git-svn)
  No changes between current HEAD and refs/remotes/git-svn
  Resetting to the latest refs/remotes/git-svn
  ...etc...
```

Answer (score 8):

You may also get this error, when you have checkout freshly created SVN repo.

I have solved this by

1. First doing an initial commit via svn command
2. Then clone the repo using git svn command.

Answer (score 2):

Another cause for this problem is a wrong `svn-remote.svn.rewriteRoot` option (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268736/git-svn-whats-the-equivalent-to-svn-switch-relocate/4061493#4061493) for instructions on using this).

The `git-svn-id` line in your commits imported from Subversion has to match the `rewriteRoot` URL if it is set.

Comment: The simple svn URL switcheroo from the linked answer here worked!

Answer (score 2):

I got this message because I used a FQDN for the `git svn init` command but the pre-existing git-svn integration was using just the hostname.

E.g. `grep git-svn-id` showed:

```
git-svn-id: svn://host/repo/...
```

But I did:

```
git svn init -Ttrunk svn://host.domain.com/repo
```

(We have a machine that regularly syncs a git repo with svn, then everyone else has `git config --add remote.origin.fetch refs/remotes/*:refs/remotes/*` to fetch down the svn synced branches.)

Comment: @jpaugh, run `git svn init` with a URL that exactly matches the `git-svn-id` value.

Comment: So, you mean you can't fix it? You have to rebuild the repository?

Comment: Concretely, when I did `git svn init -Ttrunk svn://host.domain.com/repo` I got this error.  So instead I did `git svn init -Ttrunk svn://host/repo` and everything worked fine.

Comment: Ok. I had this problem with an existing project, which had worked fine for some time. I ended up recloning the SVN project, but I was hoping there was a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this after I used BFG Repo-Cleaner https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ and rewrited git history (intentional), and then tried to git svn fetch again.
The message shows that the git <-> svn matching is lost.

To solves this, read https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn
At the very bottom shows:

> $GIT_DIR/svn/**/.rev_map.*
>
> Mapping between Subversion revision
> numbers and Git commit names. In a repository where the noMetadata
> option is not set, this can be rebuilt from the git-svn-id: lines that
> are at the end of every commit (see the svn.noMetadata section above
> for details).

You need to have the git-svn-id comments in the commit comments to do this.
If you do, you can delete the .rev_map.* file and rebuild it.

```
rm .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.*
git svn info
```

This should show:

```
Rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.{snip} ...
...
Done rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.{snip}
Path: .
...and then regular git svn info output
```

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too. And I don't remember to have done something unusual. SVN repo existed, Git version was the most recent.
There were 2 commits in local git repo that I wanted to commit to SVN. But when I ran:

```
git svn dcommit
```

I got the error.

```
git svn fetch
```

and

```
git svn rebase
```

didn't help. I got the same error after running them.

I think the problem could be caused by the fact that I did a squash of 2 local git commits previously. If it was the reason I still don't understand why a squash is a problem in this case (If you know, please, comment it).

Anyway I solved the problem by cloning the svn repo again to another working directory.

```
git svn clone .../trunk
```

Added the problematic git repo as a remote one:

```
git remote add last /cygdrive/c/data/problem_repo
```

and did a cherry-pick on all the commits that weren't yet moved to SVN. After that I could successfuly run:

```
git svn dcommit
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause: If you have an svn-remote..rewriteUUID config set, git-svn may have trouble locating the right meta-data for the repository.  For example, you might have something like this (see the git-svn man page for a discussion of why you would want to do this):

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn://read-write.test.org
    fetch = trunk/project:refs/remotes/trunk
    rewriteRoot = http://read-only.test.org/svn
    rewriteUUID = 1234-abcd
```

... where 1234-abcd is the UUID of the read-only mirror.  When you 'git svn fetch', you might end up with this file:

```
.git/svn/refs/remotes/trunk/.rev_map.5678-dcba
```

... where 5678-dcba is the UUID of the read-write repository.  The fix is to:

```
$ mv .git/svn/refs/remotes/trunk/.rev_map.5678-dcba \
    .git/svn/refs/remotes/trunk/.rev_map.1234-abcd
```

Can't say for certain whether that is a durable solution, i.e., it might get confused next time you 'git svn fetch'.  Might try a symlink rather than 'mv', I haven't experimented with that.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possible cause: trying to rebase from the wrong branch. Remember to `git checkout <your_branch>` before running `git svn rebase` in case you haven't done that.