# Git SVN, Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history after git rebase

Tags: git, version-control, git-svn, git-rebase

We're doing a two way synchronization of one single branch "basic"

I've been able to `git svn dcommit` before

When I do (in order to do the git -> svn part ,  for svn -> git , git svn fetch works like a charm)

```
git checkout -b svntrunk trunk 
git rebase basic svntrunk
git svn dcommit
```

the last command end with

```
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history
```

If I do the rebase directly on `basic`  I finish with basic being messed up with the svn version of the commit (when we've 'dcommit' before on top of the actual commits) which seems to tell me that's not the way to go

Am I missing a step ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269566/unable-to-determine-upstream-svn-information-from-head-history)

Answer (score 2):

The second command in your sequence ( `git rebase basic svntrunk` ) detaches svn-based commits from the svn's trunk and rebases them on top of the git's `basic` branch. Use `git svn info` to check the context of svn branch you are operating at. I would expect that error already after the rebase step.

What you would probably want to do is rebase your changes on top of the latest svn commit. That could be `git rebase svntrunk basic`.

If you started your `basic` branch from trunk (you may check it again with the help of `git svn info`), then mere 'git checkout basic && git svn dcommit' might be enough as `dcommit` does rebase for you.