# SVN - GIT migration issue

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I am trying to migrate my repository from SVN->GIT. I am using to git-svn commands to setup a SVN GIT mirror.
I am following https://gist.github.com/ticean/1556967 for reference. 
Migration from SVN to GIT will be a gradual process. Initially, developers will be using SVN for commits and this mirror will be used to update/sync the GIT repository on a daily basis. Later, everyone will be moved to GIT and current SVN repo will be locked.

Background:-

1. We are not following the conventional directory structure in SVN.
2. We have our code placed as https://Path_to_svn/ABC/branches/Branch/Project_Name
3. We have a git repo https://github.com/UserName/Project_Name1.git

To set up a mirror, I am using the following commands in sequence:-

1. git svn init https://Path_to_svn/ABC/branches/Branch/Project_name
2. git svn fetch:- After a long iteration through all the files in the SVN repo, this step completes.
3. git checkout -b develop
4. git checkout master
5. git reset --hard master
6. git remote add origin1 git@github.com:UserName/Project_Name1.git
7. git checkout develop
8. git svn rebase
   At this point I am getting "unable to determine upstream svn information from working tree history" error.
   I have tried steps mentioned in [Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269566/unable-to-determine-upstream-svn-information-from-head-history) but no help.

Thanks in Advance..!!

Comment: Do you understand what you are trying to do in Git?

Comment: Is the svn server installed?

Comment: @Tim:- I am trying to create a GIT SVN mirror, for this I am using a intermediate branch at local to checkout the latest code and then merge and commit in GIT.

Comment: @cup:- Yes SVN server is installed.

Comment: Please update your question with what your workflow is intending to accomplish.  Giving us the above 8 steps does not make this clear.

Comment: @Tim:- I have updated the details. Let me know if further details are required. Also, please refer to https://gist.github.com/ticean/1556967. I am trying to achieve a similar functionality.

Comment: The GitHub documentation you are using is full of problems.  Please read [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296975/how-do-i-tell-git-svn-about-a-remote-branch-created-after-i-fetched-the-repo) which likely contains the information you need.  What you are trying to do is very non trivial, so brew up a fresh pot of coffee.

Comment: You should really consider migrating to git completely. Why stick to svn?We just did ourselves and for all colleagues not confident with GIT they can mostly remain their working flow.