# How do I put a new Git repo to an SVN server?

Tags: linux, git, svn, cygwin, debian

I have a git repo that I want to push to my SVN server. So I followed some tutorials on the web and I always end up with the same message.

```
$ git svn dcommit
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
Perhaps the repository is empty. at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 866.
```

Here is the latest steps I followed
https://stackoverflow.com/a/981765/1814930

I am on Cygwin64 and the SVN server is running on Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right path? Sounds to me like this could be the problem.