# How to mirror git on svn, on Windows, with a bare repo

Tags: git, svn

There is lots of information about migrating from SVN to git, but what I'm looking for is a way to mirror git to SVN, where the git repo is pre-existing, and the SVN repo needs to be brought up to date on the contents of the git repo, and subsequently be kept up-to-date. (This is a mirror, I don't need bi-directional synchronisation).

(Why? Because dev has migrated to git, but management only trusts svn. This buys us time for attitudes to change...)

Answer (score 1):

The closest I found to what I wanted was [here](http://www.kerrybuckley.org/2009/10/06/maintaining-a-read-only-svn-mirror-of-a-git-repository), but I experienced the same problem as someone in the comments there: the SVN log was polluted with merge messages.

The main problem is having two completely separate histories, and no way to permanently combine them. git-svn has to start from an existing svn repo, so the initial commit comes from there. But I don't want to permanently rewrite the history of my git repo to base it off the SVN initial commit.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981765) answer got me quite a lot of the way there, and I thought that I had finished, On first sync, it was fine, but the problem is that it attempts to rebase ALL of the history from git onto the svn branch, even though that branch already contains most of that history. This ends up trying to do 'backwards' merges (merging an old version of a file into a newer one), which gives unresolvable conflicts (which you have to do again every time).

So I switched to cherry-picking.

Anyway, here is the setup: this is a complete walk-through which creates everything locally. It can be adapted to whatever you already have.

#### Create bare git repo

```
#(create and cd to a test folder)
git --bare init bare.git
```

#### Create local git working repo

```
#(cd to test folder)
mkdir gitrepo
cd gitrepo
echo 'First content' > file.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Initial git commit"
git remote add origin [absolute path to bare.git]
git push origin master
```

At this point, the new file added to local git working repo has been synchronised to the bare repo.

#### Create empty subversion

```
svn mkdir --parents [path to desired svn repo including /trunk] -m "Initial commit"
```

#### Clone bare into a mirror repo

```
#(cd to test folder)
git clone [absolute path to bare.git] mirror
cd mirror
code .git\config # I'm using VSCode here: edit with whatever you want
```

Add the following lines to the file:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = [path to svn repo including /trunk]
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

#### Commit to svn

```
git svn fetch
git rebase --onto remotes/git-svn --root master 
git svn dcommit
```

This fetches the empty 'first commit' from svn, rebases all the changes cloned from bare repo onto it, and then dcommits back to svn. At this point all the repos are synchronised.

(Note that for an existing repo with lots of history, this may require some manual merging if there are branch/merges in the past history of `master`).

#### Setup necessary branches

Initial setup left us with `master` pointing at svn. So

```
git checkout -b svn
git checkout -B master origin/master
git checkout -b previous
```

The idea is that the `svn` branch tracks the svn remote, `master` tracks the origin/master, and `previous` points to the last sync of master/svn. In this way we can use the range of commits from `previous` to `master` to determine what to cherry pick.

#### Setup the hook

To setup so that the sync to svn step is automatic, create file `post-receive` in the `\hooks` folder of the bare repo. Contents as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# After receiving pushed commits, move to Mirror and update to svn
unset GIT_DIR # weird but without this, cd doesn't influence execution directory
cd ..\\mirror
git checkout master
git pull origin
git checkout svn
git cherry-pick previous..master
git svn dcommit
git checkout previous
git merge --ff master
exit
```

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. One year as passed: did this solution stand the test of time ? Is your mirror still working ?

Comment: Erm, it worked until we got ransomwared, SVN wasn't backed up, I still had my local git source, and management decided maybe git wasn't so bad after all :)

Comment: (In other words, we don't use SVN anymore, so we stopped needing this mirror).